# Scale all images to fit container proportionally

Tags: html, css, scale

I am building a customization script where a user can upload an image and drag it around a template image to get a desired result. The problem is the template image is over 1000px tall and wide, so I put it inside a container limiting it's height/width.

How do I make it so the uploaded image is scaled exactly the same so when I create the image via PHP I can take the `left:` and `top:` CSS values and apply them to the much larger template image and uploaded image?

Current CSS:

```
#template {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#uploaded {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: the idea is to make each image 50% scaled of its native height/width. So when applying it via my PHP I can take the pixel location of the uploaded image and apply it to my script. The original images are simply too large for anyone to manipulate so my idea is make them all appear smaller so they fit on my website and once submitted I can multiply the pixel location by 2 and create the much larger image

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Are all the images going to be uploaded as 1000px x 1000px? Can't you simply scale them down with one of the PHP classes that exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if that is what you are asking for … anyway:

The CSS3 property [`background-size: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) lets you specify that the background image of should fill out the container's size and stretch proportionally. Together with [`background-repeat: no-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-repeat) it might be what you are looking for:

```
#uploaded {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;

    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pu76s/3/