# Pseudo-element Background Reveal on :hover

Tags: html, css

---

**Summary**

- **Target devices** (Device Width **+600px** - Please **ignore** *Mobile / xs screens*)
- **Pure CSS** Image Reveal with `:hover:after`
- **Works** but not ideal
- the **Issues**:

  - image ratio ***(The images will be 800px/600px)*** is not maintained - width gets cropped instead of image being scaled down
  - Images are outside of the main container  `.outercontainer`
  - The **image fade-in** on `:hover` **works** but it does **not** fade-out after `:hover` state is **terminated** I tried using a separate animation / same animation backwards with no luck

---

**Desired Effect**:

- Everything fits inside container with the blue border labeled
  `.outercontainer`
- ***Edit:*** The images should have their own space - about 80% of the container
  width and the options/menu would be the other 20% - No overlap *(if the images overlap over the options, tablet users would be stuck in :hover state)*
- `.outercontainer` and everyting inside adjusts according to screen
  width
- Minimum desired device width to support is 600px (ignore screens smaller than 600px)
- Steps:

  - Images Fade in on `:hover`
  - Images remain visiable so long as the elemet is still in `:hover`
  - Images fade-out after the element is "un-hovered"

---

**Similar posts / issues**

- [Scale image inside div up AND/OR down to fit largest side of image with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279460/scale-image-inside-div-up-and-or-down-to-fit-largest-side-of-image-with-css) (addresses an image as an element and not as the background of a pseudo-element)
- [can't get image to fit inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428327/cant-get-image-to-fit-inside-a-div) ( same as the link above)
- [Scale all images to fit container proportionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622403/scale-all-images-to-fit-container-proportionally) (Adresses the image being the
  background of an element as opposed to it being the background of an
  :after pseudo-element)

*There are many more questions like this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fit%20image%20inside%20container%20css). I have not found one that addresses the image being the background of the :after pseudo-element*

---

**My Questions**

1. How do I fit an image displayed with :hover:after inside its parent's container ? *(I would like it to take no more than 80%-85% of the width of that container - the rest of the space should be allocated to the options/menu/list items)*
2. How can I make an image displayed with :hover:after responsive?
3. How can I make an element fade out after un-hovring it?

*My `CSS`and `HTML`are in the snippet below **(Not fully resposive - open in fullscreen please)***

```css
/* Start Miscellaneous stuff */

body {
 background: #131418;
 color: #999;
 text-align: center;
}

.optionlist a {
 color: #999;
 text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes mycoolfade {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 to {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

/* End Miscellaneous stuff */

.outercontainer {
 border: 1px solid blue; /*This needs to be in the middle of the screen and everthing should fit inside it*/
 position: fixed; /*border to highlight only - not part of final product*/
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 1200px;
 max-width: 80%
}

.optioncontainer {
 width: 250px;
 max-width: 20vw;
}

.optionlist li {
 background: #fff;
 padding: .5em;
 box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 100px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 list-style-type: none;
}

.optionlist li:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #000;
}

.optionlist li:hover {
 background: red;
}

.optionlist li:hover:after { /* The part the needs to be fixed */
 content: '';
 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 animation: mycoolfade 1s;
}

/* Start Background Control */

#red:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/)}

#blue:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/601/)}

#green:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/600/)}

#yellow:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/601/)}

#orange:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/799/600/)}

#white:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/599/)}

#black:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/599/)}

/* End Background Control */
```

```html
<body>
 The initial hiccup when the images load is not an issue 
 <div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="optioncontainer">
   <div class="optionlist">
    <li id="red">Red</li>
    <li id="blue">Blue</li>
    <li id="green">Green</li>
    <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
    <li id="orange">Orange</li>
    <li id="white">White</li>
    <li id="black">Black</li>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Edit:** *This is an image of what the whole setup would ideally look like.* 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Upvoted for the perfect and detailed way of asking a question on SO

Comment: following this question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my try

Probably I am missing something, let me know if this is the case

The trick is to make the optionlist element  widthbe always 20% of the container width.

This way, we can make the pseudo elements 400% of their parent, and this is equivalent to the 80% that remains of the container minus the optionlist.

To handle the fadeout, we need to make the pseudos present all the time (not just when hovering). So, we declare them in the base state with opacity 0, and change this to opacity 1 on hover.

This causes the bug that you detected, because the hover on the pseudo triggers even if the opacity is 0, and then bubbles to the element. This can be solved with a pointer-events: none on the pseudo.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;  
}

body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.optionlist a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* End Miscellaneous stuff */

.outercontainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /*This needs to be in the middle of the screen t*/
  position: relative;
  /*border to highlight only - not part of final product*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.optioncontainer {
  width: 20%;
}
.optionlist {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.optionlist li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 100px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  list-style-type: none;
}
.optionlist li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
}
.optionlist li:hover {
  background: red;
}
.optionlist li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
   /*background-size: cover;   */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  pointer-events: none;   /* do not trigger a hover */
}
.optionlist li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Start Background Control */

#red:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/)
}
#blue:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/601/)
}
#green:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/600/)
}
#yellow:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/601/)
}
#orange:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/799/600/)
}
#white:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/599/)
}
#black:after {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/599/)
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="optioncontainer">
    <div class="optionlist">
      <li id="red">Red</li>
      <li id="blue">Blue</li>
      <li id="green">Green</li>
      <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
      <li id="orange">Orange</li>
      <li id="white">White</li>
      <li id="black">Black</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Val!. You did manage to get the images to display within the box which I like very much! Would it be possible for the images to display in their original aspect ratio without being zoomed it? ? 800px / 600px. Please check the image I add to the question.

Comment: I have removed the background-size: cover, and added background-position to center the image Now, there won't be any image zoom. Is this the idea ?

Comment: Great work Val! I like it and I think it qualifies as an answer. There's only one small bug that occurs. The image for the last option shows up if you :hover the location where the images show while it's empty. It also shows up if you hover with cursor over any of the images when they are visible. If you can get that bug worked out, I will pick this as the answer - Also you can add a couple of lines to explain how it works but that's completely optional.

Comment: Done! Happy that you like it !

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much for your time and thank you for the explanation. This turned out to be much better than I expected! I chose this answer because it's the complete answer to the question. The only thing I changed was to increase the padding for the option list items to 1em. Other than that, perfect!

Comment: Again, thank you. Since this is what I believe that you wanted, I will give hlaf of the bounty to Denis Shremet

Answer (score 3):

Just set your `outercontainer` wherever you want. After changing the `outercontainer` `position` style to `relative` and `after` pseudo element styling to `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` seems working fine as you want. Using CSS animation you can apply the fade effect.

============ Latest Changes ==============

Added styling for `outercontainer` related to position and margin for displaying it to the center, added pseudo element `background` styling like `no-repeat` and `background-size: cover`. Changed `div` markup to `ul` and `flex` style for `ul`.

```css
/* Start Miscellaneous stuff */

body {
 background: #131418;
 color: #999;
 text-align: center;
}

.optionlist a {
 color: #999;
 text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes mycoolfade {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 to {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

/* End Miscellaneous stuff */

.outercontainer {
 border: 1px solid blue; /*This needs to be in the middle of the screen and everthing should fit inside it*/
 position: absolute; /*border to highlight only - not part of final product*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.optioncontainer {
 width: 250px;
 max-width: 20vw;
    height: 100%;
}

.optionlist {
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.optionlist li {
 background: #fff;
 padding: .5em;
 box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 100px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 list-style-type: none;
}

.optionlist li:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #000;
}

.optionlist li:hover {
 background: red;
}

.optionlist li:hover:after { /* The part the needs to be fixed */
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 animation: mycoolfade 1s;
    z-index:-1;
}

/* Start Background Control */

#red:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#blue:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/601/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#green:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/600/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#yellow:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/601/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#orange:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/799/600/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#white:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/599/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#black:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/599/)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* End Background Control */
```

```html
<body>
 The initial hiccup when the images load is not an issue 
 <div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="optioncontainer">
   <ul class="optionlist">
    <li id="red">Red</li>
    <li id="blue">Blue</li>
    <li id="green">Green</li>
    <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
    <li id="orange">Orange</li>
    <li id="white">White</li>
    <li id="black">Black</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried it on Chrome, FF, and IE and it doesn't work on any of them. The main container is stuck to the top of the page and the images don't display in full size.

Comment: Just run the code snippet here and tell me what exactly out of your expectations? For now on hover the image which is assigned to pseudo element just visible inside the ```outercontainer```.

Comment: Yeah, I ran it here on different browsers, the images are not displaying in full size, they repeat horizontally and .outercontainer is not in the middle of the screen. it's stuck to the top of the page.

Comment: Ok so you want the outercontainer in center and the pseudo element background images inside it or not?

Comment: Correct

 .outercontainer goes in the middle of the screen. Everything else fits inside of it. It Would be great if it responds to screen size. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Now have look in the new changes.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried again, it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

The fadein/fadeout part of your question:

```css
/* Start Miscellaneous stuff */

body {
 background: #131418;
 color: #999;
 text-align: center;
}

.optionlist a {
 color: #999;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* End Miscellaneous stuff */

.outercontainer {
 border: 1px solid blue; /*This needs to be in the middle of the screen and everthing should fit inside it*/
 position: fixed; /*border to highlight only - not part of final product*/
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 1200px;
 max-width: 80%
}

.optioncontainer {
 width: 250px;
 max-width: 20vw;
}

.optionlist li {
 background: #fff;
 padding: .5em;
 box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 100px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 list-style-type: none;
}

.optionlist li:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #000;
}

.optionlist li:hover {
 background: red;
}

.optionlist li:after {
    content: '';
 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.optionlist li:hover:after {
 opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* Start Background Control */

#red:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/)}

#blue:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/601/)}

#green:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/600/)}

#yellow:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/601/)}

#orange:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/799/600/)}

#white:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/599/)}

#black:after {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/599/)}

/* End Background Control */
```

```html
<body>
 The initial hiccup when the images load is not an issue 
 <div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="optioncontainer">
   <div class="optionlist">
    <li id="red">Red</li>
    <li id="blue">Blue</li>
    <li id="green">Green</li>
    <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
    <li id="orange">Orange</li>
    <li id="white">White</li>
    <li id="black">Black</li>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind! I made a note of how you did it (and that you were the first to implement this approach)  Care to try to solve the rest of the puzzle? I can't split the bounty but this answer is definitely note-worthy.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. I was able to acheive this by using `vh` and `vw` units for your `.outercontainer`  and changing the styles around a bit. Namely moving the styles from `:hover::after` to `::after` .

```
.optionlist li:hover::after {
  /* Just toggling visibility and setting animation here */
  animation: mycoolfadein 1s;
  display: block;
}


/* Start Background Control -changed style names for testing */

.listitem::after {
  content: "";
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/);
  background-size: 80vw 70vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

As far as the requirements.

- How do I fit an image displayed with :hover:after inside its parent's container?
  -by knowing the parent containers width and settting the same on the `content` pseudo element , in this case used vh and vw and used the same for the image dimensions
- How can I make an image displayed with :hover:after responsive? - same as previous , but you can also look into background-size to stretch the images into place.
- How can I make an element fade out after un-hovring it? - unfortunately i reckon we have to use JS to acheive this.

Attaching a fiddle for reference.[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lg6v27/3/)

Note: Few `li` elements will are made non-hoverable for demonstration purposes

Other links for reference, [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/) , [SO question on pseudo element visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111639/hide-pseudo-after-element-when-hovering-this-element)

Comment: Thank you! I looked at the fiddle and it is pretty close to the desired effect indeed. Would it be possible to have the image be in its own when it shows instead of being on top of the other options? As it is now, touch screens would get stuck in the :hover unless the user clicks somewhere else. This would still be the case even if the image took its own space, but then the other options would still be visible and the user can click on those.

Comment: I would also like to avoid js.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
background: #ccd;
color: #fff;

}

.damn {
width:80%;
height:80%;
border: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
.controller{
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
flex-Wrap:wrap;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
.controller li {
background: #ddd;
list-style-type: none;
width:20%;
}
.controller li:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #000;
}
.controller li:hover {
 background: red;
}
.controller li:last-child{
background:#ccc;
width:80%;
height:100%;
padding:1%;}


/* content Control */
.imgWrap{
  border:1px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
#red:hover~.imgWrap{
content:url("http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg");
}

#blue:hover~.imgWrap {
 content:url("https://www.hlf.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/siftgroups_media_fullsize/public/media/programmes/landscape_partnerships_overlooking_the_wye_.jpg?itok=HOgiVAEW&width=800&height=600")}

#green:hover~.imgWrap { content:url("http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg");
}
#yellow:hover~.imgWrap {
content:url("https://www.hlf.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/siftgroups_media_fullsize/public/media/programmes/landscape_partnerships_overlooking_the_wye_.jpg?itok=HOgiVAEW&width=800&height=600")}

#orange:hover~.imgWrap { content:url("http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg");
}
#white:hover~.imgWrap {
content:url("https://www.hlf.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/siftgroups_media_fullsize/public/media/programmes/landscape_partnerships_overlooking_the_wye_.jpg?itok=HOgiVAEW&width=800&height=600")}

#black:hover~.imgWrap { content:url("http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="damn">
  <ul class="controller">
   <li id="red">Red</li>
   <li id="blue">Blue</li>
   <li id="green">Green</li>
   <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
   <li id="orange">Orange</li>
   <li id="white">White</li>
   <li id="black">Black</li>
            <li id="showImg" class="imgWrap">a</li>
  </ul>
       
 </div>
</body>
```

it's not having a transition yet. it's not responsive yet. and it is just a simple display. or do you want me to put it in?

Comment: Obnik, thank you for the answer. The container does change it's size like I want it too, but if you resize it, you will notice that it doesn't maintain the aspect ration. Also, Yes, if it would be possible to add all the elements I described in the question, it will make it easy for me to choose a complete answer.